# IIS 6/7 Slows down ultimately while trying to access ASP.net 4 page from non-localhost computers

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, iis-7, iis-6

When I deploy my ASP.net 4 website on newly installed  IIS 6 on Win Server 2003 R2 or on IIS 7 on Windows 2008 R2, I have a very good (actually instant) access to my website pages while calling them locally, but while trying to access them from any other intranet computer, the speed slows down very badly and I can not find what is the problem. It has been become a major problem for me and my job and I've been looking for a solution but I've not detected any solutions already. Would you please helping me?

By the way the users of this website will be at max 20 persons and I've deployed my app on a very very powerful dedicated server with about 64GB of RAM and 16 CPU cores.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be created by many different things such as:

- Incorrect IIS configuration
- Incorrect Routing
- Database Latency
- Server Over utilization

I would start by seeing if a static HTML page with no code is delivered quickly.  If yes then I would look at using [ASP.NET Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) as a starting point to see where the problem in the code may be.  If No then I would look at the IIS and routing configuration for your network.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to forms authentication and I am getting very good speed results.